# Terminology question - "Chern number"

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I have seen the term Chern number used to refer to the first Hilbert-Samuel coefficient, $e_{1}(I)$, of an ideal $I$ in a local ring $(R, m)$.  (Where the Hilbert-Samuel polynomial agrees with $\lambda (R/I^{n})$ for $n$ sufficiently large and looks like $P_{I}(n)= \sum _{i=0}^{d} (-1)^{i} e_{i}(I) \binom {n+d-i-1}{d-i}$.)  I'm just wondering if this terminology is only used under certain conditions, and if anyone has a reference for where it was started.

Comment: As long as I know, Chern numbers refer to the different combination of top intersections of Chern classes. Thus, for example, if $X$ a compact complex manifold of dimension two, its Chern numbers are $c_1(X)^2$ and $c_2(X)$.

Comment: Lam, I'm guessing you're an algebraist, so perhaps Robert's book
"Multiplicities and Chern classes in Local Algebra" would be helpful.
The key point is to use (a suitably strong form of) Riemann-Roch
to link the Hilbert(-Samuel) polynomial to Chern numbers in the
 geometric sense.